# Insert on Join Tables Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I've seen several questions and answers about this, but none is quite similar to my problem, so now I am asking.

Here is the situation

I have a table called `users`, `roles`, and `user_role`

**table**:  `users`

**fields**: `user_id`, `username`, `password`

**table**: roles

**fields**: `role_id`, `role_name`

**table**: user_role

**fields**: `user_id`, `role_id`

**foreign key** of `user_role.user_id` is `user.user_id`

**foreign key** of `user_role.role_id` is `role.role_id`

My problem is when I create a user, I also want to set their roles to a default value or a selected value I chose in `<select>` element.

I tried several things like:

```
INSERT INTO users as t1 (t1.username, t1.password, t2.role)
JOIN user_role as t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
VALUES (:username, :password, :role)
```

Am I doing it super wrong?

EDIT BECAUSE OF AN ANSWER BELOW

I think something is still wrong, it gives me a blank screen

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();
$string = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES (:user,:pass,:first,:middle,:last,:course)";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($string);
$sth->execute(array(
':user'=> $data['user'],
':pass'=> $data['pass']
));

$sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id)
VALUES (' . $this->db->lastInsertId(user_id) . ', :role)");
$sth->execute(array(
':role' => 3
));

$this->db->commit();
```

Comment: if i add another insert like
    `insert INto user_role VALUES (x,y)`
i cannot set parameter x, bec. user_role.user_id hasn't been created yet.

Comment: What language do you use for your server side ?

Comment: using triggers would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like you're using PHP & PDO, this simplified code will take care of your insert:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (' . $pdo->lastInsertId() . ', ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($role));
$pdo->commit();
```

After you insert a user into the `users` table, the value returned by `$pdo->lastInsertId()` is the `id` that was just inserted into the `users` table.

Read more on [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Encase these two insert statements in a transaction and you're good to go.

Comment: wow,i haven't check that part of pdo.. it's been only a day since started pdo.., let me try to understand that

Comment: i think something is still wrong, it gives me a blank screen
`$this->db->beginTransaction();
$string = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES (:user,:pass,:first,:middle,:last,:course)";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($string);
$sth->execute(array(
':user'=> $data['user'],
':pass'=> $data['pass']
));

$sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (' . $this->db->lastInsertId(user_id) . ', :role)");
$sth->execute(array(
':role' => 3
));
$this->db->commit();
`